# How do I hide the console window?

Tags: delphi, console-application

I have a basic console window. It is blank and all my program does is run though sockets to a host computer. How do I make the black console window not visible?

I'm using Delphi 2007.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
```

from the source code...

Comment: This makes your application target the GUI subsystem rather than the console subsystem. And that's exactly what you want to do here.

Comment: I removed {$APPTYPE CONSOLE} but then it would not connect the socket...

Comment: Then your problem is elsewhere, User. The console or GUI subsystem has nothing to do with whether you can connect to sockets. Keep investigating.

Comment: I removed '{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}' in Delphi XE7, and it didn't work. Then I replaced it with '{$APPTYPE GUI}', and it worked. The console then stopped working completely of course. I needed the console for reporting possible errors, and reenabled it on demand with 'if GetConsoleWindow = 0 then AllocConsole;'

Comment: @BentTranberg Thanks for the hint. Just wondered about this on XE7 myself.

Comment: That won't work on Delphi XE7