# Prevent flashing in Delphi console application

Tags: delphi, console-application

I have a Delphi console application which does not have any write or read statements (i.e. no interaction with the console). Yet, when I run the program the console does flash momentarily on the screen.

I would be most grateful if someone can tell me how to prevent this flashing. I suspect that I have to adjust some or other compiler setting, but I can't find which one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Minimize it, move it out of screen, etc. What does it do? It is quite impossible to answer a question regarding a problem that we can't reproduce.

Comment: [How do I hide the console window?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13042036/327083)

Comment: [Delphi - Hide console window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13056642/327083)

Comment: [How to show/hide a console window app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42767078/327083)

Comment: @J... The links you have posted all have the word "Hide" in them. I think that the question is actually how to make sure that the console window is not displayed in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

If it does not write to the console, why do you make it a console application? Make it a VCL application without a form and put the code into the dpr just like with a console program.

As Craig Young pointed out in his comment:

A simpler approach is to create a console application and delete the line

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
```

Comment: While this method does inflate the application a teensy bit, it is most elegant.

Comment: it is inflated only if you enable the VCL.  If you don't actually need the VCL, don't enable it.

Comment: It's not whether it's a VCL app that matters. It's the target subsystem. Target the GUI subsystem is what is needed.

Comment: Default resources may make it large - multi-resolution icon, VCL themes... There were articles like "while minimum EXE of Delphi XE7 is so much larger than one of Delphi 7" dissecting what made EXEs grow

Comment: A simpler approach is to create a console application and delete the line `{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
{$APPTYPE GUI}
```

Instead of

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
```